# Filter Mailing List report for unsent mails

Tags: civimail

I have a mailing list with 788 recipients. When run, the hosting server choked at 520 records because of server limitations. When I run the sent/scheduled mailings report I can generate the delivery summary and can get a .csv of both the intended recipients and the successful deliveries. The list of "intended recipient" contacts has one of two entries in the Delivery Status field: Successful and Unknown.

What I need to do is  filter the original recipients list for delivery status=Unknown, but that I can't find a method to accomplish that.

I've solved the host resource limitations issue by using Mailchimp and the Joomla Mailchimp extension. Now I want to resend the email only to the 228 people the server never got to.  Is there any way? I have tried custom searches, filters, various reports, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a one time issue (now that you've resolved with MailChimp), **I would use that CSV to 're-import' those intended recipients with an Unknown status**. The CSV should have email address as a field, so you can use that to match up your contacts.  See [Importing Data](http://book.civicrm.org/user/common-workflows/importing-data/) and [Importing Data - CiviCRM Wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Importing+Data) for reference.

When you import the contacts, use the Update or Fill option for "For Duplicate Contacts" option (and they should all match if your dedupe rule uses email address). **In one of the last steps of the import, you can add them to a new group. Use that group as the recipients for your re-sent mailing.**